# Правильно ли использование класса?

Tags: c#, классы

Постановка задачи:

> Необходимо написать программу, имитирующую работу телевизора. Предусмотрите в нем возможность переключения каналов: следующий канал, предыдущий канал, переход к каналу по номеру. Учтите, что канал не может иметь отрицательный номер. При запуске программа должна показывать текущий канал и предлагать переключить канал по нажатию на какую-либо кнопку на клавиатуре. Отображать текущий канал можно просто в виде номера и названия. После запуска приложения программа должна постоянно предлагать переключать каналы и только после того, как пользователь решит выключить телевизор, завершать программу.
>
> Указания:
>
> Роль телевизора должен исполнять класс с именем TV.
>
> Класс TV должен иметь:
>
> поля:
>
> - currentChannel - текущий канал
> - channelLimit - количество каналов
>
> конструктор:
>
> - TV(currentChannel) - инициализирует свойства класса. Можно сделать еще один 
>   конструктор, в котором будет задаваться еще и количество каналов.
>
> три метода:
>
> - NextChannel() - переключает телевизор на следующий канал
> - PreviousChannel() - переключает телевизор на предыдущий канал
> - MoveToChannel(channel) - переключает телевизор на указанный канал

Мое решение:

```
using System;

namespace HomeTasks
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TV tv = new TV();
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HomeTasks
{
    internal class TV
    {
        public int currentChannel = 1;
        public int channelLimit = 5;
        public TV()
        {
            string answer;
            Console.WriteLine($"Limit of channels: {channelLimit}");
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Curent channel: {currentChannel}");
                Console.WriteLine($"\tWrite N to go next channel!\n\tWrite P to go previous channel!\n\tWrite G to go channel wich you want!\n\tWrite Stop to exit!");
                Console.Write("Enter your answer: ");
                answer = Console.ReadLine().ToLower().Trim();
                if (answer == "n")
                    NextChannel();
                else if (answer == "p")
                {
                    PreviousChannel();
                }
                else if (answer == "g")
                {
                    Console.Write("Введите число: ");
                    int numberOfChannel = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    MoveToChannel(numberOfChannel);
                }
            }
            while (answer != "stop");
        }
        public void NextChannel()
        {   
            currentChannel++;
            if (currentChannel > channelLimit)
                currentChannel = 1;
        }
        public void PreviousChannel()
        {
            currentChannel--;
            if (currentChannel < 1)
                currentChannel = channelLimit;
        }

        public void MoveToChannel(int number)
        {
            currentChannel = number;
            if (number > channelLimit)
            {
                currentChannel = 1;
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

Правильно ли я решил задачу в плане ТЗ?

Comment: `Правильно ли я решил задачу в плане ТЗ?` а вы как думаете? Есть сомнения? Какие именно?

Comment: Есть сомнения в плане того правильно ли я реализовал классы

Comment: Например? Конкретизируйте проблему. Этот код работает? Если да, то почему вы решили, что неправильно? Если нет, то что именно не работает? Если вам нужна инспекция кода, вы должны объяснить, на предмет чего вам нужно инспектировать код. "посмотрите, все ли норм?" - это достаточно субъективно получится. Один разработчик скажет "работает? - значит норм", второй найдет кучу ошибок и недочетов реализации. А если вы конкретно скажете, что вас беспокоит, то и ответ конкретный получите. В рулетку сыграем или все-таки уточните проблему?

Comment: реализовал неправильно, потому что класс не соответствует требованиям описанным требованиям в задаче

Comment: Есть небольшие расхождения - по тз может быть канал номер 0, а по коду - нет. И в тз упомянуты названия каналов - а в коде ничего такого нет.

Comment: @PashaPash, в коде 0 канал может быть.

Comment: @Grundy на него нельзя перейти по PreviousChannel

Comment: @PashaPash, да, но можно было по MoveToChannel